# How to target a checkbox that has no id, name and class attribute?

Tags: javascript, angular, cypress

I am trying to target a checkbox using cypress that has no id and classname and assert it is checked on click. I have tried a couple of ways including this and it does not work.

`cy.get('[type=checkbox]').select('Store')`

The code looks like this

```
<h2>
  <input type="checkbox" 
         tri-state="" 
         ng-model="data.root" 
         class="ng-valid ng-touched ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">Store 
</h2>
```

Comment: Hi, could you please show the message error, just to know better which is the cause of the error?

Answer (score 1):

`.select()` is for dropdowns (well some of them), but `.check()` is for checkboxes [docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/check)

```js
cy.contains('h2', 'Store')
  .find('[type=checkbox]')
  .check()
```

There's something a little bit off with the html, the `<input>` isn't closed. Probably does not matter, but to be safe id the `<h2>` with the "Store" text, then `.find()` takes you inside the `<h2>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It has worked like magic.